# Asp.Net core/Razor Pages strange session behaviour: session is thrown away every second time

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core, httpcontext

I have a Razor Pages application where I have one really simple section where the User enters an ID and gets redirected to a page that displays a certain content.

When the user enters the ID I'm setting the Session variable like this:

```
HttpContext.Session.Clear();
HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
foreach(var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
{
    Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
}
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Token", 12345);
return Redirect("/DisplayPresentation");
```

The reason why i'm deleting all the cookies and signing out, is because I want to make sure there's nothing else in the current session.

Basically i'm receiving that session value on the redirected page, simply like this:

```
int tokenId = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("Token") ?? default(int);
```

For whatever reason I cannot explain myself, every second time i'm doing this "login" process the session gets thrown away by the server, therefore the `tokenId` will be `0`.

I noticed that I have a normal Authorization system for a different section of the application, so maybe that's doing funny stuff.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
(PS: I hope I have provided enough information for the problem)

Comment: So to confirm when the user logs out, you are trying to set a value into session. When you login the first time and try to get the value form session it is there. If you log out again and then login again the value doesn't exist this time?

Comment: @Benl2 not exactly. It‘s really a basic system where a user logins with a simple token and after he entered that token the Id is set to the session and received in the redirect. I‘m using SignOutAsync() because in my app there‘s a different section where i‘m using basic asp.net user authorization and i want to make sure the cookies are not crossing over. Basically every second time a user logs in with that Token it doesn‘t work (the session is thrown away by the framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the cookies removes the cookie that keeps track of session state. So by deleting the cookies, you are effectively removing the session state and forcing a new one to be created. So:

1. Request 1, it sets up the integer in session.
2. Request 2 sets up session with the integer then deletes the session cookie which establishes a new session without the cookie.
3. Request 3 gets the new session which doesn't include the integer.

Comment: You can probably avoid this by checking if the cookie you are about to delete is teh session cookie and not deleting it.

Comment: I think that‘s the problem. I‘m basically shooting myself in the foot when deleting those cookies. I will try to find out in the loop if it‘s the session cookie or not